# Database modeling for stock prices

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I have recently been given the assignment of modelling a database fit to
store stock prices for over 140 companies. The data will be collected 
every 15 min for 8.5 h each day from all these companies. The problem I'm
facing right now is how to setup the database to achieve fast search/fetch 
given this data.

One solution would be to store everything in one table with the following columns:

```
| Company name | Price | Date | Etc... |
```

Or I could create a table for each company and just store the price and the date for
when the data was collected (and other parameters not known atm).

What is your thought about these kind of solutions? I hope the problem was explained
in sufficient detail, else please let me know.

Any other solution would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I take it you're concerned about performance given the large number of records your likely to generate - 140 companies * 4 data points / hour * 8.5 hours * 250 trading days / year means you're looking at around 1.2 million data points per year.

Modern relational database systems can easily handle that number of records - subject to some important considerations - in a single table - I don't see an issue with storing 100 years of data points.

So, yes, your initial design is probably the best:

Company name | Price | Date | Etc... |

Create indexes on Company name and date; that will allow you to answer questions like:

- what was the highest share price for company x
- what was the share price for company x on date y
- on date y, what was the highest share price

To help prevent performance problems, I'd build a test database, and populate it with sample data (tools like [dbMonster](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dbmonster/) make this easy), and then build the queries you (think you) will run against the real system; use the tuning tools for your database system to optimize those queries and/or indices.

Comment: Thank you, this gave me great insight.

Answer (score 8):

On top of what has already been said, I'd like to say the following thing: Don't use "Company name" or something like "Ticker Symbol" as your primary key. As you're likely to find out, stock prices have two important characteristics that are often ignored:

- some companies can be quoted on multiple stock exchanges, and therefore have different quote prices on each stock exchange.
- some companies are quoted on multiple times on the same stock exchange, but in different currencies.

As a result, a properly generic solution should use the (ISIN, currency, stock exchange) triplet as identifier for a quote.

Answer (score 5):

The first, more important question is what are the types and usage patterns of the queries that will be executed against this table.  Is this an Online Transactional Processing (OLTP) application, where the great majority of queries are against a single record, or at most a small set of records? or is to an Online Analytical Processing application, where most queries will need to read, and process, significantly large sets of data to generate aggregations and do analysis.  These two very different types of systems should be modeled in different ways.

If it is the first type of app, (OLTP), your first option is a better one, but the usage patterns and types of queries would still be important to determine the types of indices to place on the table.

If it is an OLAP application, (and a system storing billions of stock prices sounds more like an OLAP app) then the data structure you set up might be better organized to store pre-aggregated data values, or even go all the way an use a multi-dimensional database like an [OLAP cube](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OLAP_cube), based on a [star schema](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_schema).

Answer (score 3):

Put them into a single table. Modern DB engines can easily handle those volumes you specified.

rowid | StockCode | priceTimeInUTC | PriceCode | AskPrice | BidPrice | Volume

- rowid: Identity UniqueIdentifier.
- StockCode instead of Company. Companies have multiple types of socks.
- PriceTimeInUTC is to standardize any datetime into a specific timezone.
- Also datetime2 (more accurate).
- PriceCode is used to identify what of price it is: Options/Futures/CommonStock, PreferredStock, etc
- AskPrice is the Buying price
- BidPrice is the Selling price.
- Volume (for buy/sell)  might be useful for you.

Separately, have a StockCode table and a PriceCode table.

Answer (score -2):

That is a Brute Force approach. The second you add searchable factors it can change everything. A more flexible and elegant option is a star schema, which can scale to any
amount of data. I am a private party working on this myself.